# Convert IEnumerable<string> into IEnumerable<FileInfo>

Tags: c#, .net, linq

Is there a way to get `IEnumerable<FileInfo>` out of `Directory.EnumerateDirectories(..)` ?

My Method looks like this.

```
public static IEnumerable<String> EnumerateFiles(String path, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOpt)
{
    try
    {
        IEnumerable<string> dirFiles = Enumerable.Empty<String>();
        if (searchOpt == SearchOption.AllDirectories)
        {
            dirFiles = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path)
                                .SelectMany(x => EnumerateFiles(x, searchPattern, searchOpt));
        }
        return dirFiles.Concat(Directory.EnumerateFiles(path, searchPattern));
    }
    catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
    {
        return Enumerable.Empty<String>();
    }
}
```

I also like to Implement :

```
public static IEnumerable<FileInfo> EnumerateFiles(String path, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOpt)
{
  //...code
}
```

Comment: It is not clear, `IEnumerable<FileInfo>` from `Directory.EnumerateDirectories` ? `EnumerateDirectories` returns directories not files.

Comment: My Code looks like this: `Directory.EnumerateDirectories(path).SelectMany(x => numerateFiles(x, searchPattern, searchOpt));`

Comment: [Is this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd383571%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) what you're looking for ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [DirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413343%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead

Comment: Do I get Files in Subfolder too?

Comment: `EnumerateFiles` has an overload which accepts `SearchOptions` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd413343(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @SmillaJ. Yes, sorry I must have linked the wrong one apologies. I will update.